# Login with Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

I'm struggling with some questions regarding adding "login with facebook" support to my website.

Say a new user visits my site, and they want to register. They click Join, then "login with facebook" and they authorize my app. I get a callback with their FB Id and auth token. I can then create an account in my system for them and let them get on with using my site.

Presumably I should still set my own auth cookies and use those for determining if a user is logged in? Presumably I only need a new FB auth token to interact with the FB API, so if I don't need to do this I can disregard any auth token (although realistically I will store it).

I know this sounds simple and obvious, but I just wanted to check. The FB docs are rather sparse on best practices.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set your own auth cookies and use them for determining if a user is logged in.

If you want to determine whether the user is currently logged-in or not, you can check that any time using `FB.getLoginStatus()` or `$facebook->getUser()`.

To interact with the Facebook API, you can use the **user access token** that can be returned when user login/authorizes the app. Its validity is upto 2 hours. If you need you can **extend** its validity upto 60 days and store it. See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending) for more details.

You can also use **[app access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens)** (never expires) to publish content to Facebook on behalf of a person who has granted the publishing permission to your application.

Comment: but how do i determine server-side if a user is logged in without having to worry about the lifespan of an access token? An access token can expire at any time (typically hours iirc) which means when a user returns to my site after that, the server will think they are logged out. Do I misunderstand

Comment: See, a user visits your app, you can check if he's logged in or not (using fb api); if not then call login and get the token; else you'll get the token anyway. Then, extend the token just to make sure it doesnt get expire soon enough; then do whatever you want to do with the token. I'm not sure if I'm able to convince you or not, or may be i misunderstand.

Comment: i think its the token extension part, doesnt that require a client side call to facebook? if you can do it server side then thats problem solved

Comment: If you check the link i've posted (for extending the token), you'll see that its a server-side call only. Hope it helped!

Comment: `Even the long-lived access token will eventually expire. At any point, you can generate a new long-lived token by sending the person back to the login flow used by your web app`. I also can't see anywhere in the literature that describes how to check if the user is still logged in to FB from server-side only. Am i blind?

Comment: When do you want to check "a user is still logged-in in"?

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is simply to use FB as your authentication mechanism, then I'd say that you are correct - there's no need to keep the FB auth token.  Just use your own cookie, and set your own timeout protocol.